# Wrong text in wordpress theme, how do I change?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, gettext

I am using a custom theme with [Scriptburn WordPress Movie plugin](http://wpmovies.scriptburn.com/)

Please look at this [**Website**](http://www.z777.in/watch-tvshow-criminal-minds-free-online.html).

I would like to replace all wrong **"session"** text occurrence by **"season"**.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

Added the code of the page in the theme (Page name is single-shows.php):

```html
<?php
the_post();
/*
$url="http://nosvideo.com/?v=71nub74616hq";
$ret=apply_filters('wpmovies_convert_to_embed', $url);
die("$url => $ret");

 */
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();
$post_details = get_post_details($current_post_id, true, 'publish', $fresh = false);
//print_nice($post_details);
if (!$post_details || $post_details['post_status'] != 'publish')
{
    wpmovies_404_page();
    exit();
}
$post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

$image = get_correct_poster($post_details, 'featured', $current_post_id);

$genres = $post_details['genres'];
$tags = $post_details['tags'];
$actors = $post_details['actors'];
$directors = $post_details['directors'];

$runtime = $post_details['runtime'];

$release = $post_details['release'];

$views = $post_details['views'];

//$views = $views + 1;
//inc_post_view($current_post_id, $post_type, $views);

$quality = $post_details['quality'];

$imdb = $post_details['imdb'];

$links = $post_details['links'];
$rating = $post_details['rating'];
$post_name = $post_details['post_name'];

$post_title = $post_details['post_title'];
$post_link = $post_details['permalink'];

$episode_detail = (($post_details['episode_detail']));
$s = (integer) get_query_var('session');
$e = (integer) get_query_var('episode');
$bysession = false;
$bylinks = false;

$title[] = "<a class='H_title' title='$post_title' href='$post_link'>$post_title</a>";
$episode_title = $post_title;

$title_text = $post_title;
$session_text = array();
if ($s && isset($links[$s]) && count($links[$s]))
{
    $bysession = true;
    $title[] = sprintf("<a class='H_title' title='$post_title %s$session' href='$post_link?session=$s'>%s -$s</a>", __('S', 'wp_movies_theme'), __('S', 'wp_movies_theme'));
    $session_text[] = sprintf(__("S -%s", 'wp_movies_theme'), $s);
}
if ($e && isset($links[$s][$e]))
{
    $title_text = $title_text . " " . __("season", 'wp_movies_theme') . " -$season " . __("Episode", 'wp_movies_theme') . " -$e";
    $bylinks = true;
    $title[] = sprintf("<a class='H_title' title='$post_title %s$season %s$e' href='$post_link?season=$s&episode=$e'>%s -$e</a>", __('S', 'wp_movies_theme'), __('E', 'wp_movies_theme'), __('E', 'wp_movies_theme'));
    $session_text[] = sprintf(__("E -%s", 'wp_movies_theme'), $e);
}
$title = implode("&nbsp;", $title);

$post_name = $post->post_name;
//$title=get_the_title();
$url = $post_details['permalink'];
$similar_posts = $post_details['similar_posts'];

$session_text = implode(" ", $session_text);

/*
$page_title = sprintf("Watch %s %s%s online free", readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), $post_title, $session_text);
$box_title = sprintf(__("%s %s%s ".(wpmovies_get_setting('direct_links')?'':'link'), 'wp_movies_theme'), $title, readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), trailer_text($plural = false, $space = true));

$extra_box_title = sprintf("%s %s", $title, readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false));
 */

$page_title = str_replace(["%1", "%2", "%3"], [__(readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), 'wp_movies_theme'), $title, $session_text], __("Watch %1 %2 %3 online free", 'wp_movies_theme'));
$page_title = str_replace(["1٪", "2٪", "3٪"], [__(readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), 'wp_movies_theme') . " ", $title, $session_text . " "], $page_title);

//$page_title = sprintf(__("Watch %1 %2 online free",'wp_movies_theme'), readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), $title);
$box_title = $title . " " . __(sprintf("%s%s ", readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), trailer_text($plural = false, $space = true)) . (wpmovies_get_setting('direct_links') ? '' : 'link'), 'wp_movies_theme');
$extra_box_title = $title . " " . __(readable_post_type($post_type, $plural = false), 'wp_movies_theme');

wpmovies_set_page_title($page_title);
$style = wpmovies_get_setting('direct_links') && wpmovies_get_setting('player_top');

get_header();

if ($style && $s && $e)
{
    ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">


    <div class="panel panel-default"   style="height:auto" >
      <?php
render_direct_links($post_details, $s, $e);
    ?>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<?php
}

page_header(false);?>

<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <?php title_box($page_title, false, "", "");?>
      <div class="panel-body"  style="overflow:visible"  >
        <?php link_page_common_details($post_details, $s, $e);?>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php
$sorted = false;
if ($s && $e)
{
    $mode = wpmovies_get_setting('link_mode');
    $param1 = @base64_decode(get_query_var('lk'));
    $param2 = @base64_decode(get_query_var('ttl'));
    $param2 = $param2 ? $param2 : "Watch Movie " . $title;
    if ($mode == 'inpage')
    {
        if (!$param1)
        {
            $sorted = true;
            $post_details['links'][$s][$e] = wpmovies_sort_array($post_details['links'][$s][$e]);
            $i = 0;
            while (isset($post_details['links'][$s][$e][$i]))
            {
                $param1 = @array_values(@$post_details['links'][$s][$e][$i]);
                $param1 = $param1[0]['link'];
                $embed_link = apply_filters('wpmovies_convert_to_embed', $param1);
                if (isset($embed_link['embed_url']) && isset($embed_link['embed']))
                {
                    $embed = $embed_link['embed'];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    $i++;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $embed_link = apply_filters('wpmovies_convert_to_embed', $param1);
            $embed = @$embed_link['embed'];
        }
        if ($embed)
        {
            ?>


 <div class="panel panel-default" id="inpage_embed">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="padding-right:5px">
      <h1 class="panel-title">
<?php echo ($param2); ?>
              </h1>
    </div>
      </div>
</div>
 <div class="panel-body" style="text-align:center"   >
 <?php echo ($embed) ?>
 </div>
 </div>

            <?php

        }
    }
}

if ($s && $e && isset($post_details['episode_detail'][$s]))
{
    $pst = $post_details['episode_detail'];
    //print_nice($pst[$s]);
    $first_episode = key(array_slice($pst[$s], 0, 1, true));
    $last_episode = key(array_slice($pst[$s], -1, 1, true));

    $prev_episode = $e == $first_episode ? $first_episode : $e - 1;
    $next_episode = $e == $last_episode ? $last_episode : $e + 1;

    $prev_epiosde_link = "$post_link?session=$s&episode=$prev_episode";
    $next_epiosde_link = "$post_link?session=$s&episode=$next_episode";

    ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body"   >
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block <?php echo ($e == $first_episode ? 'disabled' : ""); ?>" href="<?php echo ($prev_epiosde_link); ?>"><?php _e("Previous Episode", "wp_movies_theme");?></a></div>
       <div class="col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" href="<?php echo ("$post_link?session=$s"); ?>"><?php _e("Back to Session", "wp_movies_theme");?> <?php echo ($s); ?></a></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" href="<?php echo ("$post_link"); ?>"><?php _e("Back to Session List", "wp_movies_theme");?></a></div>

       <div class="col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block <?php echo ($e == $last_episode ? 'disabled' : ""); ?>" href="<?php echo ($next_epiosde_link); ?>"><?php _e("Next Episode", "wp_movies_theme");?></a></div>
 </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<?php }

if ($s && !$e)
{
    $pst = $post_details['episode_detail'];
    //print_nice($pst[$s]);
    $first_episode = key(array_slice($pst, 0, 1, true));
    $last_episode = key(array_slice($pst, -1, 1, true));

    $prev_episode = $s == $first_episode ? $first_episode : $s - 1;
    $next_episode = $s == $last_episode ? $last_episode : $s + 1;

    $prev_epiosde_link = "$post_link?session=$prev_episode";
    $next_epiosde_link = "$post_link?session=$next_episode";
    ?>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body"   >
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block <?php echo ($s == $first_episode ? 'disabled' : ""); ?>" href="<?php echo ($prev_epiosde_link); ?>"><?php _e("Previous Session", "wp_movies_theme");?></a></div>
       <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" href="<?php echo ("$post_link"); ?>"><?php _e("Back to Session List", "wp_movies_theme");?></a></div>
       <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block <?php echo ($s == $last_episode ? 'disabled' : ""); ?>" href="<?php echo ($next_epiosde_link); ?>"><?php _e("Next Session", "wp_movies_theme");?></a></div>
 </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<?php }
?>


        <?php
$i = 0;
if ($s && $e)
{

    if (!$style)
    {
        if (wpmovies_get_setting('direct_links'))
        {
            ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default"   style="height:auto" >
      <?php
render_direct_links($post_details, $s, $e, $sorted);
            ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
        else
        {
            ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <?php title_box($box_title, true, "", "");?>
      <div class="panel-body"   >
      <?php

            render_links($post_details, $s, $e);
            ?> </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
    }
}
else
{

// if show home page opened
    session_area(@$post_details['links'][$s][$e], $s);
}

?>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php link_page_common_extra($post_details, $extra_box_title, $s, $e);

?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
function session_area($links, $s = "")
{

    global $i;
    global $bysession;
    global $post_details;
    // print_nice($post_details['episode_detail']);

    $cnt = count($post_details['episode_detail']);
    $first = floor($cnt / 2) + ($cnt % 2 ? 1 : 0);
    $second = $cnt - $first;
    $row = 1;
    //echo("$cnt-$first-$second");
    ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 ">
    <div class=" special list-group" id="acord_links<?php echo ($s ? '1' : ''); ?>"  >
      <?php

    if (count($post_details['episode_detail']) && is_array($post_details['episode_detail']))
    {
        foreach ($post_details['episode_detail'] as $session => &$episodes)
        {
            $st = epiosde_area($session, $episodes, count(@$post_details['links'][$session][$episode]));

            if (!$session || $s && $s != $session || !$st)
            {
                continue;
            }

            ?>
      <div class='bg-info'><a    class="special list-group-item  large  list-group-item-switchhon-blog <?php echo ($s ? '' : 'acord'); ?>"  <?php if (!$s)
            {
                ?> data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#session-<?php echo ($session); ?>" <?php }
            ?>>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Session <?php echo ($session); ?> <?php if (!$s)
            {
                ?><span class='small text-info'><?php _e("Click to view Episode list", "wp_movies_theme");?></span>  <?php }
            ?></a>
      </div>
      <div id="session-<?php echo ($session); ?>" class="collapse <?php echo ($s ? 'in' : ''); ?>" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="list-group special" style="margin-bottom:0px" >
              <?php

            echo ($st);
            ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php }

    }
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}

function epiosde_area($session, $episodes, $count)
{
    ob_start();
    global $post_details;
    foreach ($episodes as $episode => $link)
    {
        if (!$episode || !isset($link['title']))
        {
            continue;
        }
        $tm = strtotime($link['release']);
        ?>
              <a     href="<?php the_permalink()?>?session=<?php echo ($session); ?>&episode=<?php echo ($episode); ?>" class="list-group-item  medium  special  text-success"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#session-<?php echo ($session); ?>">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 ">E<?php echo ($episode); ?></div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 hideOverflow"><strong><?php echo (wp_trim_words($link['title'], 10)); ?></strong> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 hidden-sm1 hidden-xs "><?php echo ($tm ? date("d-M-y", strtotime($link['release'])) : ''); ?>  </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 text-right"><?php echo (count(@$post_details['links'][$session][$episode])); ?> links </div>
              </div>
              </a>
              <?php

    }
    $st = ob_get_clean();
    return trim($st);
}
?>

<?php page_footer(false);?>
```

Comment: If you happen to have Notepad++, you can try entering `Control + F` and click on the "Find in Files" tab. Change the directory to point to your wordpress installation (you probably have to download all the files if you don't have it locally) and enter "Session" for the search term and search. This will tell you which files to update. You might want to check the "Match case" checkbox so it doesn't match `$_SESSION` variables

Comment: ill try add the code now, and yes i bought theme from scriptburn.com

Comment: I am looking at your code… It will be easier than before, to find out what is wrong.

Comment: ok how can this be done

Comment: LoicTheAztec please answer my emails/skype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Scriptburn WordPress Movie](http://wpmovies.scriptburn.com) plugin. Your problem is on template single-shows.php of this plugin.

Your problem is near line 328:

```
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Session <?php echo ($session); ?> <?php if (!$s)
```

Replace by:

```
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><?php echo __("Season", "wp_movies_theme"); ?> <?php echo ($session); ?> <?php if (!$s)
```

This will solve this issue.

Comment: I need the change to be permanent for all tv shows , i dont see sessions in custom fields

Comment: session is not there?

Comment: thanks it worked , cheers for your help